# Activeadmin query for every attribute label on database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, activeadmin, rails-i18n

Using `i18n-active_record` for mult locales. It works fine on my site.

But the issue I am facing is that in `activeadmin` page take too much time to load and when I see logs it query on translation table for every label

e.g

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `translations` WHERE `translations`.`locale` = 'en' AND (`key` IN ('activerecord.models.admin') OR `key` LIKE 'activerecord.models.admin.%');

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `translations` WHERE `translations`.`locale` = 'en' AND (`key` IN ('active_admin.resources.article.new_model') OR `key` LIKE 'active_admin.resources.article.new_model.%');

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `translations` WHERE `translations`.`locale` = 'en' AND (`key` IN ('formtastic.labels.q.index.title') OR `key` LIKE 'formtastic.labels.q.index.title.%'); 

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `translations` WHERE `translations`.`locale` = 'en' AND (`key` IN ('formtastic.labels.q.title') OR `key` LIKE 'formtastic.labels.q.title.%');
```

Due to this there is lot load on database as admin panel usage is more and for every column there are 200+ queries on translation table

How to load activeadmin without locales?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

> Following the convention over configuration philosophy, Rails I18n provides reasonable default translation strings. When different translation strings are needed, they can be overridden.
>
> Rails adds all .rb and .yml files from the config/locales directory to the translations load path, automatically.
>
> The default en.yml locale in this directory contains a sample pair of translation strings

You need to store your translations in a YAML file in your app itself rather than a database. For example your first translation would be:

```
# config/locales/en.yml

activerecord:
  models:
    admin: translation_required_for_this_locale
```